# Initializing properties of static class fails with null value exception

Tags: c#, initialization, static-classes

I have a static connection factory class and need to initialize the connection parameters from configuration

```
namespace MyApp.Common.LinqToDB
{
    public static class MyConnectionFactory
    {
        public static string Authority { get; set; }
        public static string Target { get; set; }
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public static string ClientId { get; set; }
        public static string ClientSecret { get; set; }
        private static ClientCredential ClientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);

    public static IDbConnection createConnection()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Target, ClientCredential).Result;
            SqlConnection MyDataConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            MyDataConnection.AccessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            return MyDataConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

From the main parogram I try to initialize these properties

```
MyConnectionFactory.Authority = "blahblah";
```

this throws a null value exception inside the static class. The value does not get to the class.

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Workspace.Common.LinqToDB.WorkspaceConnectionFactory' threw an exception.
  Source=Common
  StackTrace:
   at Workspace.Common.LinqToDB.WorkspaceConnectionFactory.set_Authority(String value) in 

........
Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: clientId
```

Is it wrong to set the values of static properties of a static class.
I know about static constructor() but it does not take a parameters and I need to set the connection parameters.
Is static factory not the right pattern for a connection factory. I can make this whole thing work if I don't make the factory static, but that does not seem the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private static ClientCredential ClientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);` would be compiled as:

```
private static ClientCredential ClientCredential;

//Static constructor
static MyConnectionFactory()
{
  ClientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);
}
```

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Now, when you try to assign `Authority`, the static constructor have to be called before. At this point, `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` are still null, which is causing the exception.

Comment: When you try to set it, the constructor have to be called before, since it is static. `ClientId` at this point is still null, so `new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);` would throw an exception

Comment: Sorry, but the exception is not in ```new AuthenticationContext(Authority);```  It is in the property setter. I cannot understand what is wrong with setting a static class's static properties anytime I want.

Comment: I edited the answer, please check it as it is hopefully clearer

Comment: Understood. So the null value exception that points to the set method of Authority property is actually due to the static ClientCredential call. Thanks for your insight. I would never have guessed it. I had moved it there as an optimization. It was in createConnection() initially. Moving it back there solved the problem. Many thanks.